# Bank sites are protected by their own adblocking software

Tags: malware

I do not currently have any adblocking software or extension. Ads are flourishing on foxnews and some other sites but not on my banks page. Do banks use some their own addblocking software?

Comment: Why would a bank block ads when it's far easier for them to just not serve ads?

Answer (score 3):

Ads are typically only seen on sites that have chosen to have ads on them.

Ads have always been a source of income for a lot of media companies, so it's not really a surprise that they have chosen to have ads on their websites. On the other hands, advertisements for banks are often seen, but that's about as far as banks have ever involved themselves with the advertising industry, and they have a source of income  that's quite independent from their websites, so they don't need that revenue.